# Looking for the name of a perceived performance JavaScript technique

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance

I ran across a fascinating article from an e-mail list on Javascript performance. I can't remember the name of the technique or the phrasing in the article, and that e-mail is long gone.

The idea suggested in the article is that simple/trivial tasks performed on a webpage - such as posting a status update, voting in a poll, or giving thumbs up/down - should seem instantaneous. To achieve that, presume the AJAX request will be successful and go ahead and make a visual change on the page to indicate success (append the status update, display the poll results, etc.) **as soon as** the user completes the action.

I thought the technique was called something like "presumptive JavaScript" or "pseudo-performance something-or-other" but those searches don't return what I'm looking for. Do you folks know what I'm talking about? Any good links to helpful articles?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you are referring to is a blog post by Alex McCaw who originally named it "Asynchronous User Interfaces" (AUIs):

http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/asynchronous-ui

The reply posted by Joseph referring to a technique used in multiplayer games is actually called "dead reckoning." Back in the 1990s when we were using 56k dial-up modems, latency was a severe problem in real-time multiplayer games. To mask latency, "dead reckoning" was introduced in games such as Quake where a player's path was extrapolated based on his predicted direction, velocity, etc.

Here's an article I remember from back then that used this jargon: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3230/dead_reckoning_latency_hiding_for_.php

Dead reckoning is still used today. The innovation primarily involved the use of extrapolation over interpolation: rather than waiting for packets to arrive and interpolating (which would always be behind the real events), extrapolation is used to try and predict where a player or object might be. However, the real event does *not* "replace" the prediction. If the previous prediction was incorrect, we use any new data that arrived to try and create a more accurate new prediction rather than just "teleporting" the player or object to the correct new position.

The same principles should be applied to UI design. How can you design your asynchronous UI so it provides the best prediction? If the prediction fails, how can you avoid "teleports?" For example, in a poll, if you're providing predicted poll results, and your predictions are way off and you subsequently "correct" your prediction by providing substantially different results, it would only serve to confuse the user when the "correction" arrives. So while it's up to your creativity here, you can use existing techniques such as "prefetching" in the poll example.

Comment: Hmm, that Alex Maccaw article is round about the concept I was looking for, though not the technique name I was thinking of. He seems to suggest providing no "processing" feedback and letting the user assume their action performed without errors. (I'm not sure I agree with him on getting rid of the "Sending" notification on Gmail, but I can see where his heart is at.)

Comment: The article I read used Twitter and Facebook as prime examples of this technique. When a user posts a status update, js closes the form (sending it to the server in the background) and appends their new message to the UI, giving the user the impression that it posted immediately (instead of the ~1500ms it might _actually_ take to update the database and return "success").

Comment: Okay, I found this [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Asynchronous-UI) Alex Maccaw did that explains real-world usage of this concept, so this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @RogerP!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, sounds similar to ["lag/latency compensation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_%28online_gaming%29#Solutions_and_lag_compensation) in games, where the computer compensates by predicting (with confidence) what happens next. If what really happens contradicts with the prediction, the real event replaces the prediction.

The [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) framework also uses this technique.

Answer (score 1):

The specific article I was looking for was written by Luke Wroblewski entitled "Mobile Design Details: Performing Actions Optimistically" - http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1759. (@RogerP's reference to Alex McCaw pointed me in the right direction when I heard the word "Optimistic").

LukeW writes about real world examples of choosing to be optimistic that an AJAX request will return success and preemptively update the UI to indicate success.